# Defending Castle from Zombies

Tags: magic, weapons, medieval, zombies, siege

**TL;DR**: You're defending coastal medieval fortress with help of about 1000 people from attack of zombies.

Long version: In my fantasy world, I'm dealing with problem of how would you defend city against zombies. Defenders are very limited in terms of magic and thus, for the purpose of the scenario, it can be treated as medieval defence.

Zombies on the other hand, are low tier magical undead. They are basically corpses, who are reanimated and conserved with magic. Their principle of reanimation uses original muscles of the body, but they feel no pain. To stop them you need to either destroy their head (which is used by magic as core of reanimation) or at least destroy the muscles. In terms of strength, they might be somewhat stronger than normal human, but not by much, and with limited movement coordination, they actually pose threat only due to large numbers.

I'm thinking about what kind of defensive siege weapons could be used to defend against them? 
For example: Is heated sand hot enough to cause serious damage to muscles, or does it only do surface damage that wouldn't affect such zombies? Are there any wise strategies that you could employ in event of such castle defence?

In this scenario, we're talking about a case where a castle built on a small peninsula, which only needs to be defended from the land-side. About a thousand of defenders is forced to deal with around three thousand zombies a night, for a few days. While zombies aren't fast nor smart, and tall walls of the castle are barrier they can't break, they can actually climb on the walls, with principle similar to geckos.

Additional Details: City wasn't built to defend against zombie invasion. Weapons it has are meant to deal with mortal demihuman invaders, so are the walls.
Firearms are not a thing.
Niche ideas based on modern knowledge are useful, but provided it's something that can be done quickly improvised.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97999/discussion-on-question-by-failus-maximus-defending-castle-from-zombies).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The best news is that the gates are safe.  Mythbusters did a show which included zombies storming a gate.  In their demo, they put all the "zombies" in protective tubes.  Why?  Because their zombies were human volunteers, and it was actually rather easy for the outside individuals rushing the gate to crush those at the gate.  If your zombies made a rush for a real reinforced gate, they'd quickly reduce the front lines to goo.

And they're not smart enough to actually bombard the castle with proper siege weapons.  This leaves just the case you worry about -- these zombies can climb the walls like a gecko.

Personally, I'd go for weapons that work like windshield wipers along the walls.  Heavy tree trunks attached at the top of the castle, sweeping back and forth.  This should knock the zombies down without wasting consumables.  Falls from that height are *going* to do damage to the head of the zombies at some point.  At the very least, it will do enough damage to permit you to set fire to the zombie bodies in a fuel-efficient manner.

Also, if they only come at night, I'd be digging pits during the day.  Pits are a wonderful way to concentrate the zombies to get maximum bang for your buck.  You're really looking to make this siege as effieicent as possible.  By your numbers, there are 20x more zombies than humans.  While we have seen such utter dominations in the past (Cannae comes to mind), it's really hard to take on that many individuals without running out of ammunition.  Any breaks in the siege should be sized upon and leveraged to replenish stockpiles.

Comment: Just have people stand on top the walls with axes, and hack off the zombies hands as they reach the top.  Big axes too, you're not fighting, just chopping.

Comment: I like the idea of using tree trunks to wipe the zombies. I however fear that some zombies could hold onto the trunks.

Comment: @FailusMaximus It depends on their velocity.  The laws of momentum apply to zombies as well.  That being said, they just have to serve as a force multiplier.  Any zombies which manage to grapple with the trunks can be opposed by normal means as they climb up.  As long as a good portion of zombies fail to grab the logs, it'll do it's job.

Comment: @FailusMaximus it may not matter so much if the zombies can hold onto the trunks so long as they aren't able to continue to climb whatever the trunks are attached to. I was going to write an answer very similar to this using a giant pendulum to clear the walls and a mechanical winch/crane to draw the pendulum back once it lost enough momentum hitting zombies. Any clinging zombies could be cleared during this process

Comment: tie two sturdy ropes to a large log, drop log of wall crushing zombies, pull log back up, rinse, repeat. Works even better with a windlass, and almost as well with a rock instead of log.

Comment: i more worried using pendulum style end up scratching or chipping the stone wall or even worse accidentally knocking the wall or tower  and the worst result end up stumbling the wall, because i think it need quite close to the wall surface to knock this zombie acuratelly especially straight wall (since they are climbing like gecko which is pretty close or stick with the wall) not using stair which have some certain angle for easy climbing also the zombie movement may end up ruin the trajectory or whatever it was called.

Comment: @ john i delet my comment since i though you mean a straight drop down not pendulum style like titan guilotine from snk. just to make sure you mean pendulum or a straight drop down? if it drop down then just as i say it may end up become elevator or a new way to climb the wall if the zombie manage to grab or hold or stop it and require a lot of it for each row of walls, also not worth it if to pull it up it require human to pull it not from some machinery and better just straight throw stone or any hard and heavy object directly unless the material is limited which is unlikely.

Comment: @John I like that idea.  In fact, it reminds me of how they roll backdrops up and down in the theater.  Two ropes wound the opposite way makes it easy to drop and pick the log up again.

Comment: @LiJun just a straight drop, no risk of damaging the wall. yes people will need to lift it but people will need to lift whatever you use, and windlass will make it a two man job. It doesn't matter if the zombies hold on just don't lift it all the way up. they won't stay on it long. In a siege every material is finite you can run out of ftoppables and you will need a lot fewer logs to cover the whole wall than anything else. It can also easily be built from the wall after the siege starts. Just be sure to let if fall all the way to the ground so the wall is not taking the jolt from stopping it.

Comment: @John For a "rule of cool" story or movie, this is a really cool idea. From a more realistic point of view, launching logs or rocks tied to ropes is far more complicated, greatly more tiresome and hugely less effective than just whacking them with weapons. The very first thing the logs touch is going to impart a certain horizontal speed to them so they get away from the walls. So the zombies below will be protected by those above; then, when the defenders pull the log up they just can stop climbing and *sit* comfortably on the log as if it was a chairlift.

Comment: @Rekesoft the mass difference means deflection is minimal.  Remember castle walls ore often not completely horizontal but slightly angled. If you are worried about a few lucky ones riding the log up, so what you have to knock one or two down normally for every dozen or hundred you take out with zero risk, that's still a big improvement. Not that will get anything from  hanging on to it, these are not intelligent creatures who will be waiting for an opportunity and there will not be much pause between stopping at the top and dropping again. the fall alone will do a lot of damage.

Comment: Hey Cort, appreciate this could be its own questions somewhere but just in passing, have you ever saw your windshield-washing-tree-trunk-on-a-rope-head-masher referenced anywhere? I thought of it before as well and am actually thrilled to see someone else make mention of the idea. Cheap, effective, easy to make, seems an obvious idea but I don't think it is in Walking Dead, Max Brooks, Night/Dawn/Day... anywhere?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I have not seen one.  In my head, it's a mashup of Edgar Alan Poe's The Pit and the Pendulum and one of the siege weapons in the defense of Paris from the TV series "Vikings."  I don't think the windshield-wiper approach is all that effective for real sieges because there's better tools available.  However, with zombies that climb walls like Geckos, it starts to become more of a natural tool.

Answer (score 70):

**Nothing**

You don't need nothing special. As the late Tywin Lannister put it, *"a man above the walls counts as ten men below"*. That's why throughthout history, castles and fortifications were rarely stormed, but sieged. A hundred men on the castle could easily stop a thousand attackers. 1000 men against 3000 zombies? They won't even tire.

Give them clubs, maces or hammers, anything blunt and solid, and let them smash the heads of the zombies as they get close. If the zombies are climbing like geckos, they need their hands on the wall to climb, so they can't stop the blows.

Comment: +1 agree totally.  Worth mentioning that unlike a "normal" battle where the defenders' actions are hampered by the need to wear armour and take cover to avoid incoming missile fire, the defenders in this situation can wander around in full view without armour because the zombies lack the smarts to use missiles.  However, illumination is critical in this situation - all good on a moonlit night, but if it is overcast then reliable oil lamps are needed.

Comment: Fetchez le vache! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQ8jGqdE2iw

Comment: its like zombie whack-a-mole!

Comment: It gets interesting when the mage responsible for the zombies puts mortal snipers behind the horde. Nice distraction, no one notices feathered shafts sprouting out of chests until it's too late.

Comment: His son had something to say about impregnating forts and/or taking female dogs with just a couple handful men. Don't even need to be too skilled. His son outlived him and saw quite some epic battles.

Comment: Tywin was an optimist.  More serious writers put the ratio at 5 to 1.

Comment: This is the right answer. The OP needs to up his zombies by a factor of ten to make it really life and death.

Comment: Put the clubs and axes in windmills and automate the strategy.

Answer (score 16):

**Grease The Walls**

You have big strong walls and unarmed opponents that can climb. Paint the walls with grease, oil, lard. You don't need to win and you don't need to kill them all, just keep them out for a few days (well nights anyway)

Zombies don't use fire so it's not a risk to buildings. Personally 3000 a night against 1000 armed guards isn't even much of a challenge. That's just three zombies per person per night. Some axes for heads, spears for poking and hammers for fingers, the humans should be able to fight that number off with no assistance.

Comment: Given the 3-1 ratio, do you even need to waste delicious lard? The defenders probably need the energy it provides a lot more than the walls.

Answer (score 14):

How close to a gecko toes are their hands? Geckos are the masters of climbing so it would be good to see the limits of your zombies.

Specifically whether they can climb across horizontal surfaces. If not, you could have a outwards inclined wall to ward them off

[image]

Zombies are in red. The one falling down says "ahhhh!" (splash)

The good guys are in green. They are partying.

The blue part must be long enough so that the falling zombies do not make a heap higher than the walls (see for instance the very beginning of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLWCgMVf6U0). Bonus if you can cover it with Teflon.

Comment: Or put slits in the bottom of the blue to poke the zombies.
You dont need to actually hit the head. because if you break a zombie bone, any muslce relying on that bone is disabled as well

Comment: @Hobbamok: your idea cold also be automated, with some kind of large comb pushing the zombies currently on the blue part though the slits, in a repetitive manner (to be calculated depending on the speed of a zombie climbing horizontally)

Comment: @WoJ or the free trunks mentioned in comments on other posts. You could also construct hoarding with murder holes in the bottom.https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Caerphilly_Castle_hoarding_exterior.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Mindless monsters that can only attack from one side, and you've got only very limited magic?

This reminds me of a mindless game from the Shockwave Flash era - which, in terms of internet, is about middle ages. The game is called *Defend your Castle*. You played it by clicking and dragging:

[image: Defend your Castle]

*"But Renan"*, you say, *"this is a fantasy setting, not a computer videogame!"* Yeah I know, different escapism mode for geeks. Well, turns out in Dungeons and Dragons there is a level 5 spell called [***Bigby's Hand***](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/bigbys-hand) - Actually a consolidation of many different spells from the second edition. It works just like that cursor. Don't believe me just because I'm saying it:

> You create a Large hand of shimmering, translucent force in an unoccupied space that you can see within range. The hand lasts for the spell’s duration, and it moves at your command, mimicking the movements of your own hand.
>
> (...)
>
> When you cast the spell and as a bonus action on your subsequent turns, you can move the hand up to 60 feet and then cause one of the following effects with it.
>
> (...)
>
> **Grasping Hand**
> The hand attempts to grapple a Huge or smaller creature within 5 feet of it. You use the hand’s Strength score to resolve the grapple. If the target is Medium or smaller, you have advantage on the check. (...)

Just grab a zombie, move it up some four dozen feet in the air and release. Gravity will do the dirty work. Rinse and repeat until you win.

Remember that every extra wizard or sorcerer is another helping hand, so bring your friends!

Comment: I used to play that game for hours.  +1 for finding a reason to make an old browser game relevant to worldbuilding.

Comment: But "Defenders are very limited in terms of magic and thus, for the purpose of the scenario, it can be treated as medieval defence."

Answer (score 8):

A good old moat will do its job of keeping attackers away ([image source](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/01/16/medieval-castles/))

[image: castle moat]

Then your defenders can focus on taking rid of those accessing the bridge, and as [the battle of Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae) has shown, good use of terrain act as force multipliers.

Comment: How does a moat stop zombies? I keep thinking back to Pirates of the Caribbean when the undead pirates walk along the bottom of the sea.

Comment: @Thorne, OP specifies defense is needed only from land side, thus these are not merzombie

Comment: @Thorne dead bodies tend to float. Not sure on the precise characteristics of OP's zombies but I'd expect a more or less mindless dead body to not walk on the bottom, as it doesn't even reach it. *Humans* should be more dangerous, as they can construct stuff to bypass a moat...and yet history has shown that moats tend to be good at keeping them at bay.

Comment: @VLAZ  since you say the dead body float, i expect the zombie can unintentionally form bridge like how ant form bridge from their companion body https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r04kAnzgjR4/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @LiJun dead bodies float just about. They don't float enough to support another body on top of theirs.

Comment: Dead bodies float if the stomach is intact. They will sink if ruptured. Just a note for all the budding serial killers out there.

Comment: @LiJun yes, they would EVENTUALLY "flood" over the moat.
But zombies being  already handicapped in terms of coordination, and the "ground" (stacks of floating zombies) is really shaky, you can expect them to tumble over each other even more, breaking some arms and legs in the process (which disables that extremity).
ALSO: Once they get wet, they weigh more, which hinders their climbing a lot

Answer (score 7):

If the walls are sloped instead of straight vertical you could effectively remove zombies by building a log storage next to the top of the wall and rolling logs down the wall whenever a group of zombies get near the top. This method would be easy enough to engineer and sure to crush and remove any zombies in the path of the log as it rolls down the wall. Workers could then go outside the next day and pull the logs back into the castle to be reused as many times as needed.

Comment: Even with vertical walls, this wouldn't be a bad idea. Attach the logs to ropes, and you have a multi-use squeegee.

Comment: Perhaps planks sticking out as a platform should be good enough - zombie climbs to the top, then (stupid that they are) tries to climb along the underside of the planks. I assume here that the zombie ability to grip is outweighed (geddit?) by the rest of the zombie.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the defenders have fireproof fortifications, and a few days to prepare, they can get by with zero casualties.

They need to pile dry brush around their walls, preferably soaked in something flammable.  Wait for the zombies to walk all the way into the brush, then light it.  The fire spreads, and the zombies, being too dumb to avoid it, just stand in the fire and burn up.

Comment: Castles sometimes used hot oil or tar to do the same thing. Pour it on the front lines to get them scorched, then throw a torch a torch and let them burn. This would have the effect of being mostly self cleaning, too. The fire would reduce the bodies mostly to ash, which would wash away. Anything left could be further reduced in later attacks. This way, the defenders don't have to remove bodies to prevent the later attacks from just walking up the pile to the top of the wall.

Comment: A significant fire against a large section of the wall of your fortification is going to be bad news for anybody inside, I think... Smoke, heat, walls weakening from the thermal stress, possibly a nasty suffocating updraft or even a huge fire vortex surrounding the castle.

Answer (score 3):

The zombies somehow have super-adhesive gecko wall-climbing powers? Magic, I suppose? How fast can they climb?

I would tend to think, since they're not much stronger than typical humans at best, they still would not climb all that fast, and would still need to use their hands, and bare hands, to do so.

You gave the defenders 1000 men? How long is the top of the battlements along which they must defend? It sounds to me like they probably have at least ten times more men than they need.

What Hollywood and TV seem to have mostly failed to communicate to most people is that it's ridiculously easy to defend a battlement. The zombies here would be climbing up from below with at least one hand busy hanging onto the wall. Defenders would stand above them behind a battlement, and could just drop rocks on them, knock them off with pole weapons, and the ones that got farther would be immediately bashed and chopped with with medieval hand weapons (axes, maces, polearms) by multiple people standing above them, before they could get in any sort of position to fight back. Only feeble or incompetent or outnumbered or surprised or otherwise incapacitated defenders would have any problem defending in that situation.

There are many historical cases where only a handful of men were able to defend a castle from assaults for prolonged periods, because it's very difficult to get up and over a castle wall when there's anyone on top to kill you as you try.

If you want another trick for defending the wall, try a large spiked ball dangled from a chain, that you sweep along the width of a section of wall, knocking off climbers.

Comment: Honestly, my attempt is to simply have almost noone die during defence, so I was mostly searching for ideas to make defence even more sucessful. I am well aware of how insane defenders' advantage was.

Comment: @FailusMaximus I think with so many defenders, they don't need much except ordinary medieval hand weapons. The zombies would be offering themselves as targets about as easily as could ever be hoped for.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the zombies, castles would be *very effective* against zombies.  They're meant to withstand sieges, after all.  That's the whole point of them.  Thus, if the zombies are mindless and cannot use siege weapons themselves, a group of 1,000 people could easily repel them.  Using slings to hit the zombies with stones would probably be an effective way to break the zombies apart, since arrows wouldn't do much damage to them.  Just keep chucking rocks at them to gradually dismember them, and you'll be good.  Rocks are easy to come by and it would not be hard to make slings for a hundred people.  Plus, it would not be difficult to train people to use them with some effectiveness.  Other kinds of weapons meant to drive of intelligent attackers would be just as useful.  Most of all, I think flaming pots of oil would be especially potent, since the zombies would be consumed by the flames.  Of course, you'd have to consider setting the area around them on fire as well, so that could be a big deterrent against that particular weapon.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for reminding me of slings, those are very good idea that I for some reason didn't take in account. As someone who studied a lot about hussite warfare, I feel very ashamed of not coming up with that on my own, since it is very obvious weapon of choice for more than one reason.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it!  I've had plenty of times where I overlooked something that, in retrospect, should have been obvious.  But, really, a castle is going to be a lot easier to defend from zombies than a lot of modern structures, since those are not designed to withstand sieges.  Zombies are also, by their nature, in a state of at least partial decomposition, so bludgeoning them into pieces is a lot easier than it is with most living creatures.  A castle is a GREAT place to be during a zombie uprising.

Answer (score 2):

as other answer already say, do as fortification usually do.

like throwing stone or brick or other hard object from the crenelation or machicolation if the zombie try to climb (hopefully crush their head or bone to make them unable to move) or try to burn them with any flammable object.

also if the castle have water moat i suggest it link with strong current or wave like from river or ocean or put a creature that can eat the zombie in the moat or it contain flamable thing like oil just in case the zombie can pass the water since i assume they dont need oxygen to breath and they still can float to move or swim or just walk through the bottom of water by wearing heavy stuff like metal armor.

my concern is more on your food supply though if your zombie never rot, since i expect they dont really need to eat while your men still need food for energy.

but honestly i dont think someone will need castle to defend against zombie they have advantage in attricion if they dont rot to cancel the magic, by turtling yourself it will only increase dead body into zombie from unfortified village, in my opinion you need is offense and bait (use cavalry since i doubt the zombie can ride or is there a horse zombie too?) to entrap them to flammable area like flammable forest or plain full of dry grass and burn the area or goes to higher place and lit a balls of hay and roll it to the zombie bellow or other type of fire trap or tactic.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tree trunks as wipers, all you would need is a tether, such as a chain or rope, and a heavy weight, such as a big rock.  Using a pendulum action it could either deal significant damage to the zombies by smashing into them, or just cause them to lose wall contact and fall.  Keep the counter weight and tether well greased to inhibit seizure by the zombies. If a zombie did manage to grab the anchor you would have several options;  Increase swing to have centrifugal force remove them, hoist them up to the waiting weapons of your rampart defenders, or drop the whole thing to the ground.  Rocks and rope are abundant and expendable and will give the zombies no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

**Big shredder/grinder on the road the castle.**

The thing about mindless attackers is that they don't think where they go, so placing a giant two shaft shredder on the road to your castle (with a drawbridge to allow people walking during the day) will probably be enough to process them from undead attackers to biological waste.

If some actually make it through - your classic castle defence techniques are your friend - throwing rocks, shooting flame arrows or dumping boiling tar on them should do the trick.

Now if you want efficiency - you can make it water powered, like a river mill, or you could make water flow below it to wash the unwanted biological waste away, you could add an angled slippery slide that would make sure the zombies can't escape the shredder etc.

And where to get that in simplies form? While not easy - digging the needed hole quickly should be possible with this many people, the shredder mechanism could be created from stone (mill stones for example) and connected through a shaft to whatever powered the city mill or other human powered mechanism could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question and I thought I'd give my input! I was at Pembroke Castle (in West Wales) over the long weekend. This seems like a great castle to use as an example as it was never taken by siege, despite having stood for around 925 (from memory) years.

Now part of the reason for this amazing legacy is that they are surrounded from most sides by the sea, but I'll pass over that obvious advantage since we are talking existing city rather than "best place to build", and it sounds like you've already got a pretty good location.

I'm going to talk murder holes, but I see no reason for this not to be extended to just tipping over the sides of the walls to deal with the zombies.

- As you've mentioned - **Sand**.

  - An advantage of this is that it doesn't matter if these zombies are wearing chain mail (as I assume they are probably ex-soldiers in walking dead form. Even plated armour will struggle to contend, since the sand can get through all the crevices. When this is heated hot enough... it would definitely cause some muscle damage.
- **LimeStone**

  - When heated, there is eminence strain put on the rock. When it hits below, it will essentially explode. Medieval shrapnel bomb.
- **Pee**

  - No honestly, don't laugh. Best bit about this is it doesn't need to be sourced from outside the walls. You have a whole city creating the stuff and it's a waste product! Great thing about super-heated pee? It turns into uric acid - it's corrosive! This will definitely do some damage to the muscle, if enough is poured.

Next, pokey holes - not sure what they are actually called. 
Add some slits into the wall and stab anything that gets too close with a spear to the head. Make sure they are too narrow for the Zombies though.

Answer (score 0):

In ye olde day, hot oil used to be dropped to those trying to burst the gate.

That will do a lot of tissue damage aswell as musculature, especially if you send a flaming arrow down after it.

Comment: Yeah, fried zombies sound like a good idea. I'll need to do some research on how to make oil, because it's not supposed to be in my castle's inventory. Thanks

Comment: @FailusMaximus bee answer have provide some alternative like boiled pee as far as i know most of boiled oil is made of animal fat or you can use boiled water instead most historical medieval use boiled water but i dont know will it damage the muscle or not seems more on damaging the skin or giving extreme pain but i also suggest tar too or greek fire if your castle know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is really the other way around.

How can any number of dumb zombies ever hope to get into a castle without smart human guidance?

Siege warfare is difficult; it takes mining, siege engines and elaborate earthworks to have any chance of success.

I challenge you to find a way that the zombies could win, given how easy they are top lure into situations where they can easily be destroyed one by one. The defenders can just build a narrow ramp witha  trap door at the end leading to a meat grinder (with suitable bait just out of reach) and mash the zombies one at a time.

Comment: Zombies winning scenario is the most basic one - depleted resources such as food and water inside the castle..

Comment: If there were enough zombies they'd climb up each other to form a huge ramp to the top of the wall, and the rest could swarm over. At 10 zombies per cubic meter, 3000 would form a ramp about 8meters high and wide. If they're completely brainless and form a ramp the length of the wall, you're probably safe. If they're smart enough to make a cone they'll get higher.

Comment: @RobinBennett What's the angle of repose for zombies?  And, what's the mass/strength ratio - with enough pressure, the bottom zombies will essentially liquefy...

Comment: @Chronocidal - excellent questions! I was guessing 45 degrees, but you're right, it could turn into a slippery mess. I think I've seen a similar question before, but can't find it.

Comment: As I understand it the zombies are attempting to assault the castle and the challenge is killing them rather than lifting a siege. Forming a ramp would require a degree of intelligence and coordination, and if they had that, they wouldn't need to form a ramp!  I think your numbers are a little low, and there will likely be a moat too... and human bodies are not a good building material.

Comment: It's easy. You need the same number of zombie as this question. But instead of storming, the zombie is sieging instead. And it will take a long time.

Comment: That won't work because as the question says, it's a coastal fortress so the defenders can keep getting supplied from the sea.  Unless the zombies have a navy, which seems unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw a penny in..

give everyone a nice light weight cane/ 'don't actually know what this is called' but it's the same principle, a cane but on the end it has a C shape, for hooking things. Use one of those and simply lift the zombies chin so it's centre of gravity is pushed away from the wall and they fall off.

although this has already been stated, just by pushing the zombies off.. the difference is the mechanism, people suggested maces/hammers/axes all of which will tire you out, if you have to survive all night, even with soldiers on shifts they will get tired and that is when you're going to get vulnerable

Answer (score 0):

I forget what it's called but some castle walls had the top area wider than the wall itself.  This meant that any ladder had to be free-standing, it couldn't rest on the walls.  There were also murder holes in the part that extended to permit attacking those trying to climb up from a position of very good cover.

Just because a zombie can climb a castle wall (remember, they're going to be rough, not slick.  I recall a bit of news out of China of a castle where some people would climb the wall simply to avoid paying admission) doesn't mean they can climb an overhang.

Answer (score 0):

You stated this is a fantasy setting, so what if you fight fire with fire? There's no way these zombies just *exist*, most likely a necromancer is sending them to distract those inside the castle from the *real*threat. However, if a necromancer can raise zombies to life, logic follows they can command zombies, or else why would you do it?
In other words, why not have your resident necromancer take care of defending the castle with his zombies?
They won't tire, they'll be directed through telepathy (I assume) so no problems with "mindless zombies", and they're completely expendable. Of course, if you *have* a necromancer, he could just take control of the incoming zombies....something's not right here, the enemy necromancer must have something truly diabolical planned to negate this huge disadvantage. Perhaps the resident necromancer is secretly on his side?

Answer (score -1):

Location, Location, Location! Set up your castle on the rocky coastline at the steepest point. If the sides are not steeply sloped, do some construction work and get those sides in top-top near vertical shape. Like this:

[image]

Now all of the horde must cross a very narrow chasm or work they're way around the heights. All you have to do is push them off. Maybe you force them to walk around the castle's side and have a section of wall that moves in and out forcing them to fall (ala RPG style) or maybe you simply roll big objects down the bridge across the chasm. Maybe you run out of stuff and simply have the troops set a phalanx with their full length scutum shields and start pushing zombies over the edge.

A person can very easily break a leg on a bad fall from 10 feet. You're tossing zombies over the edge of 100 feet or more, possibly also tumbling down the slope after the initial hitting of the deck.

Bones will break, limbs snapped in two or bent backwards; heads spilled out on the rock. Should your zombie survive the fall, they'll be a mangled mess. It really doesn't matter that they don't feel pain - limbs don't function broken. So, there they lay at the bottom of the cliff until the magic runs out or the next zombie to fall crushes their skull on its way down.

Comment: Downvoted because the author clearly states where his fantasy castle is positioned. This answer is very unhelpful.

Comment: @neophlegm haven’t seen many rocky coastlines there buddy?

Comment: "Set up your castle in the mountains atop a ledge"

Comment: @neophlegm there. Changed one sentence for you. The answer was still perfectly applicable to a coastal castle. My thanks for being so very literal.

Comment: The question is about defending a coastal CITY from zombies, not a remote mountain castle.

Comment: @Chieron really? From OP: *You're defending coastal medieval fortress* and *we're talking about a case where a castle built on a small peninsula*

Comment: @Hueco: *Long version: In my fantasy world, I'm dealing with problem of how would you defend city against zombies.*  *Additional Details: City wasn't built to defend against zombie invasion.*  Though the question is a bit confusing, switching between city and castle, suggesting some language barrier.

Comment: @Chieron OP may use those interchangeably but they also mention "medieval fortress" - those are quite clear in their construction. We're talking about a fortified city where the main inhabitants live within the city walls or have quick access to them. So, explain to me how the answer, now applied directly to the coast and requiring no imagination at all, still doesn't apply?